RuntimeError on backpropagation in a GAN model for Graph Embeddings
I am trying to learn how to create GANs on graph embeddings but keep encountering the error

RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, label_dim, noise_dim, embedding_dim):
      super(Generator, self).__init__()
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(label_dim + noise_dim, 64)
      self.fc2= nn.Linear(64, embedding_dim)

    def forward(self, label, noise):
      label = label.unsqueeze(1).float()
      x = torch.cat([label, noise], dim=1)
      x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
      x = self.fc2(x)
      return x


class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim):
      super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, 64)
      self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
      x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
      x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(x))
      return x

subset_size =1000
batch_size = 32
num_epochs = 100
noise_dim = 32
embedding_dim = 32
label_dim = 1


graph_embeddings = torch.stack(graph_embeddings_list).to(device)

dataset = TensorDataset(graph_embeddings,indexed_labels_tensor)

subset_indices = torch.randperm(len(graph_embeddings))[:subset_size]
subset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, subset_indices)


dataloader = DataLoader(subset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')


generator = Generator(label_dim=label_dim, noise_dim=noise_dim, embedding_dim=embedding_dim).to(device)
discriminator = Discriminator(embedding_dim=embedding_dim).to(device)

optimizer_G = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=0.0002)
optimizer_D = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=0.0002)

criterion = nn.BCELoss()


for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for n, (real_embeddings, labels) in enumerate(dataloader):

        real_samples_labels = torch.ones((real_embeddings.size(0), 1)).to(device=device)
        generated_samples_labels = torch.zeros((real_embeddings.size(0), 1)).to(device=device)

        print("Generated samples shape: ", generated_samples_labels.shape)
        print("Real samples shape: ", real_samples_labels.shape)


        real_embeddings = real_embeddings.to(device=device)
        labels = labels.to(device=device)


        latent_space_samples = torch.randn((labels.size(0), noise_dim)).to(device=device)
        generated_samples = generator(labels, latent_space_samples)

   
        all_samples = torch.cat((real_embeddings, generated_samples)).to(torch.float32)
        all_samples_labels = torch.cat((real_samples_labels, generated_samples_labels)).to(torch.float32)

 
        discriminator.zero_grad()

        output_discriminator = discriminator(all_samples)

        print("Discriminator output shape:", output_discriminator.shape)
        print("Discriminator output:", output_discriminator)

        loss_discriminator = criterion(output_discriminator, all_samples_labels)

        print("Discriminator loss before backward:", loss_discriminator.item())
        loss_discriminator.backward()  
        print("Completed backward pass for discriminator")
        optimizer_D.step()

    
        generator.zero_grad()

        latent_space_samples = torch.randn((labels.size(0), noise_dim)).to(device=device)
        generated_samples = generator(labels, latent_space_samples)

        output_discriminator_generated = discriminator(generated_samples)  
        loss_generator = criterion(output_discriminator_generated, real_samples_labels)

        print(f"Before generator backward pass - epoch {epoch}, batch {n}")
        loss_generator.backward(create_graph=True)
        print(f"After generator backward pass - epoch {epoch}, batch {n}")
        optimizer_G.step()


        if n == len(dataloader) - 1:
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch} Loss D.: {loss_discriminator.item()}")
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch} Loss G.: {loss_generator.item()}")


I tried to create a simple GAN to calculate graph embeddings with a relation to the Labels. But the error occurs at the loss_discriminator.backward() part.
I think the procedure was correct. I tried to detach and recompute the output_discriminator in the loss_generation but all to no avail.
